# Unable to run prepared statement because user variable is too long?

Tags: mysql, variables, prepared-statement, pivot-table, user-variables

### The issue

I have a working stored procedure (SP) that accepts 3 parameters (an id, a from date and a to date). This SP works fine in my test system where all of the values returned from `t1.name` in the `GROUP_CONACT` are rather short and there aren't many in the `GROUP_CONCAT`.

The issue is that when I put this in to the LIVE system, there are a few more questions to add to the `GORUP_CONCAT` and the `t1.name` values are a lot longer than expected.

From the outcome I can see when trying to debug the script, it appears that the issue is that the variable `@SQL` is not able to store all the information provided back from the `GROUP_CONACT` query.

### The Code

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `team_analyst_results`(in var1 int, in var2 DATE, in var3 DATE)
BEGIN


  SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(question_id = \'',
                  question_id,
                  '\', Pass, Null)) AS ',
                  CONCAT('\'', t1.name, '\'')))
  INTO @SQL FROM
      smhubdb.questions t1
          INNER JOIN
      smhubdb.check_questions t2 ON t1.id = t2.question_id
          INNER JOIN
      smhubdb.quality_checks t3 ON t2.check_id = t3.id
          INNER JOIN
      smhubdb.users t4 ON t3.check_person = t4.id
  WHERE
      t4.team_id = var1
  AND
    t3.checked_date BETWEEN var2 AND var3
  GROUP BY t3.check_person;

  SET @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT t1.id AS "'"Check ID"'", t4.name AS "'"Name"'" ,DATE_FORMAT(t1.checked_date, "'"%d-%m-%Y"'") AS "'" Check Date "'" , ', @SQL, ' , t1.notes AS "'"Notes"'", CONCAT(ROUND((SUM(CASE WHEN t2.pass = 1 THEN t3.value ELSE 0 END) / SUM(t3.value) * 100),0),"'""'") AS "'"Score"'" FROM smhubdb.quality_checks t1 LEFT JOIN smhubdb.check_questions t2 ON t1.id = t2.check_id LEFT JOIN smhubdb.questions t3 on t2.question_id = t3.id INNER JOIN smhubdb.users t4 ON t1.check_person = t4.id WHERE t4.team_id = ''', var1 ,''' AND t1.checked_date BETWEEN ''', var2 ,''' AND ''', var3 ,''' GROUP BY t1.id ORDER BY t1.id DESC');


  PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
  EXECUTE stmt;
END
```

### What I tried

I tried to set `@SQL` as a local variable (Obviously this dropped the @) but I then get an error attempting to prepare the statement at the bottom of the code explaining that it is not expecting the local variable.

### The Purpose of the code

The code is used to populate a pivot table from an unknown number of results. Meaning that I need the first `GROUP_CONCAT` section to build the column names on the end statement to prepare.

### Expected output

The number of questions will not be know, nor will the name of the question.

```css
table, td, th {
 border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<th>
Name
</th>
<th>
Check ID
</th>
<th>
Date
</th>
<th>
Question1
</th>
<th>
Question2
</th>
<th>
Question3
</th>
<th>
Question4
</th>
<th>
Notes
</th>
<th>
Score
</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
Joe Bloggs
</td>
<td>
1
</td>
<td>
08/11/2018
</td>
<td>
Pass
</td>
<td>
Pass
</td>
<td>
Null
</td>
<td>
Pass
</td>
<td>
Some Notes
</td>
<td>
75%
</td>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Search for `group_concat_max_len`

Comment: I hadn't even thought of there being a limit on the GROUP_CONCAT. Do you know if changing this value requires a DB restart?

Comment: I would just change it per session in your procedure: `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=1000000;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the value of [`group_concat_max_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len). 
To do so, you can run

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=..;
```

However, once your database is restarted, this parameter will no longer be effective. To permanently change the value of `group_concat_max_len`, you need to add the following line under `my.cnf` file:

```
[mysqld]
group_concat_max_len=..
```